# How to solve an EOF error when reading a binary file

Tags: python, eof

```
class CarRecord:                    # declaring a class without other methods
  def init (self):                # constructor
    self .VehicleID = ""
    self.Registration = ""
    self.DateOfRegistration = None
    self.EngineSize = 0
    self.PurchasePrice = 0.00

import pickle                       # this library is required to create binary f iles
ThisCar = CarRecord()
Car = [ThisCar for i in range (100)]

CarFile = open ('Cars.DAT', 'wb')   # open file for binary write

for i in range (100) :              # loop for each array element
    pickle.dump (Car[i], CarFile)   # write a whole record to the binary file

CarFile.close() # close file

CarFile = open( 'Cars.DAT','rb')    # open file for binary read
Car = []                            # start with empty list
while True:                         # check for end of file
    Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile))# append record from file to end of l i st

CarFile.close()
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: `while True:` is an infinite loop. You don't stop when you get to the end of `CarFile`.

Comment: maybe save a list at the file instead of many objects, and then just read all of the file?

Comment: As a side note, I recommend using the `with` syntax for opening your files. See [this link](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve an EOF error when trying to open and read a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53814576/608639)

Comment: Do not post duplicated questions.

Answer (score 4):

what about this?

```
while True:  # check for end of file
    try:
        Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile))  # append record from file to end of l i st
    except EOFError:
        print('EOF!!!')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to catch `EOFError` in your loop…

You can't read forever from a file that does not contain infinite data, so you need to put a way for the loop to stop.

Also, there is absolutely no need to have those loops, you can directly store the list, and it will just load the list.

Comment: If he stores the list, he should make sure that the list contains distinct objects. Currently he's creating 100 references to the same object.

Comment: Ah true, I had not noticed that… it's probably not what he's trying to do.